# How to avoid duplicate values from queryset

Tags: django, django-views, django-orm

I am having three models

```
class Records(Model):

    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name="records_plan", null=True)
    observation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

class Plan(Model):
    plan_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    plan_size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              related_name="%(class)s_size", null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)


class Size(Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    order = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

In this I need to draw a chart of plan based on size of the plan

my initial queryset is

```
qs = Plan.objects.values('plan_size__value').annotate(
    count=Count('plan_size__value'),
).order_by("-plan_size__order").distinct()
```

Using this query i'm able to get a queryset with data and field

The same queryset I would like to apply a filter on later stages of my code

```
qs =  qs.filter(records_plan__rating = 'low')
```

In this case I am getting the output , but values are duplicating (Example, if a plan having two records my chart need to consider it as a single plan , but here it comes as two plans),how to fix this

Or how do I get the distinct value of plan while filtering it with record model

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to `.annotate(..)` the `Size` model?

Comment: Yes , It annotate to count of plan_size__value 

plan_size is the foreign key filed name from Plan model to Size model 

value is the value in Size model

Answer (score 0):

You are using `plan_size__order` field for `order_by` and `distinct()` is implemented on that field. later you are using other field `records_plan__rating` for filtering. So here you need to explicitly specify `distinct()` for `records_plan__rating` to get distinct results.

Comment: Could you please help me with the query

Comment: qs =  qs.filter(records_plan__rating = 'low').distinct('records_plan__rating')
this may solve your problem.

Comment: This only work for postgres sl , I am using my sql

Answer (score 0):

YOu probably should annotate your `Size` object, not the `Plan` object:

```
Size.object.filter(
    plan__records_plan__rating='low'
).annotate(
    number_of_plans=Count('plan', distinct=True)
).order_by('order')
```

The `Size` objects that arise from this will have an extra attribute `.number_of_plans` with the number of related `Plan`s for that `Size`.

The `distinct=True` is necessary if you do not want to count each plan *per* low rating. For example if a `Plan` has five `Record`s and three have a low rating, with `distinct=True`, we still count that plan *once* without `distinct=True`, we will count this three times.